# How to use percentiles in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a code that can calculate 10 percentiles out of a matrix consisting of two values for each row: the numer of worked hours and the wage. The  percentiles shall be based on the wage, but show the average worked hours for the individuals within the wage span.

In total I have about 3000 rows in my matrix, but here is how the data looks like (the real data has no headlines, I just put them in here to make it more readable):

```
Wage/h   Work(h)
12       1572
15       1671
32       1782
78       1254
22       0
```

I understand that `prctile` must be the right function to use, but I do not know how to use it. Thankful for all help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `prctile` to compute the percentiles of your data. You can then use `bsxfun` and `>=` to compare each data point to each of the percentile values. You can then use `cumsum` to provide a group index for each data point and then use `accumarray` to compute the mean for each group.

```
% Compute the percentiles
percentiles = prctile(data(:,1), 0:10:90);

% Determine which percentile each wage is within
tmp = cumsum(bsxfun(@ge, data(:,1), percentiles), 2);
group = tmp(:,end);

% Compute the mean hours for each group
mean_wages = accumarray(group, data(:,2), [], @mean);
```